# Not loading text

Tags: laravel, adminlte

I have a laravel application running alright in localhost.
I sent it to server. Database and everything already configured.
I use adminlte library for laravel (https://github.com/jeroennoten/Laravel-AdminLTE)

The problem is text is not being showed, as you can see in the image.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDjQc.jpg

How to show the correct text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED renaming resources/lang/vendor/adminlte/pt-br to pt-BR

Answer (score 0):

Try commands below

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan view:clear
```

In most of the cases this is a cache problem.

Comment: It didn't solved. Anything else I can do? How is called that kind of reference to text in laravel?